# Using html mailto to send variable or multiple variable values into the body of the email

Tags: html, mailto

I am trying to use the mailto in order to put variable values into the body of the email using this code:

```
<p>
This is another mailto link:
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someoneelse@example.com&bcc=andsomeoneelse@example.com&subject=Summer%20Party&body=You%20are%20invited%20to%20a%20big%20summer%20party!" target="_top">Send mail!</a>
</p>
```

Then I would like the end user to be able to copy and paste those values into excel easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I found. It uses JavaScript :

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:'+EmailVairable+'?subject='+SubjectVariable+'&cc='+CCvariable+'&bcc='+BCCvariable+'&body='+BodyVariable">Email</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however I was after something to put in the body of the email also. That is where I wanted a variable also.

Comment: Oh That's easy. Just editing the answer. And remember that the variables should be defined and initialized in a script tag in the head or in the body but before the anchor tag.