# Mailto With variables instead of textboxes

Tags: php, html

I want to do something like this:

A user see a picture that isn't allowed on my site. Now he clicks the Report button and the mailto window is opening.

Actually I have a textfield and a textarea on my site. This looks not good.
What I want to do is:

Instead of having textboxes or textarea I want nothing on my site except the submit button.
If a user press the button an mailto should pop up with subject Image got reported and for body should be my variable for pictureid and picture title.

Should looks like this:

admin@mysite.de
Image got reported
pictureid= 15
title=big window

```
$html .= '<form action="mailto:admin@mysite.de">';
$html .= '<input name="subject" type="text" />';
$html .= '<textarea name="body"></textarea>';
$html .= '<input type="submit" value="Report" class="ug-styled-button">';
$html .= '</form>';
```

Comment: This is easily found by searching for mailto variables. Here is a JS solution, the variables are the same you can use in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496309/using-html-mailto-to-send-variable-or-multiple-variable-values-into-the-body-of

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mailto variables in the mailto link

example:

```
 mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Image%20Report&body=pictureid=$picture_id&%20title=$image_title
```

You have to escape the variables $picture_id and $image_title